# Hide WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX with condition

Tags: wix, windows-installer

My setup consists of 6 features.
I have feature named "Server".
If Server feature is not installed WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX  should be disabled or hidden.

```
<Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 AND NOT Installed</Publish>
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#exefile]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch application"/>
```

Comment: Old question with no answer, mine usually get deleted. I've the opposite problem my checkbox has stopped appearing and I can figure out what I did that broke it.